# Security Implications of Azure AD App Registration

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I'm referring to the Azure documentation on [Application and service principal objects in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals).

I would like to understand the **security implications of allowing users to register an application in Azure AD**.

I couldn't find any documentation that explained who and who should not have the permission to do so and for what reason.

More specifically the use case is letting the owner of an Azure subscription create an ARM Service Connection in Azure DevOps. This implies registering an app in Azure AD (for this service connection).

So my question is: are there any good reason to deny the owner of an Azure subscription the permission to register applications in Azure AD?

What are the general risks or security considerations?

Answer (score 0):

Only a subscription owner can define IAM for a service principal (service connection), just because you can create them it's useless without the right permissions.

But.....

If you keep on creating principals with the similar names (not following any form of naming conversion) you are very close to making a human error by giving a wrong service principal unwanted access. This can lead to potential security incidents.

Also, as an admin you will have a lot of unused 'junk' service principals in your directory. Cleanup becomes very hard with cowboy developers -demanding for them to be retained.